# Got 2 errors with 'start' and 'update' error CS0111: Type 'Enemy' already defines a member called 'Start' with the same parameter types how can i fix?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, compiler-errors

Got 2 errors from 1 script and dont know whats happening.
If anyone can help that would be great.
Error is in the title and the other one is the same except instead of 'Start' its 'Update'

Thanks for reading!!

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float health = 50f;
    private Rigidbody rb;
    
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = this.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }
    
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 direction = player.position - transform.position;
        float angle = Mathf.Atan2(direction.y, direction.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        float y = Quaternion.identity.eulerAngles.y;
        float z = Quaternion.identity.eulerAngles.z;
        rb.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(angle, y, z);
    }
}
```

Comment: Id guess you already have another class called enemy

Answer (score 0):

Using the `override` operator should get rid of the compiler errors, but I'm not a Unity dev so I'm not sure if Unity will treat your class in the correct way. Here's how you would do it:

```
    override void Start()
    {
    ...
    }
    
    // Update is called once per frame
    override void Update()
    {
    ...
    }
```

You can read more about the override operator here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/override

I also found [this article](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Start.html) and it declares `Start` as an `IEnumerator` rather than a `void` so that may fix it too.

Comment: both didnt fix unfortunetly but thanks for looking into it!

Comment: Don’t need override in unity